# Export svg without anti-aliasing in Inkscape 1.0 by command line

Tags: inkscape, export, anti-aliasing

Inkscape 1.0 has the choice to export svg to png without anti-aliasing by GUI:
[image]

I want to export svg to png from the command line without anti-aliasing, but I'm not able. I've read the Inkscape man page but it doesn't tell anything about Antialiasing mode as in the GUI. Is it possible to export svg without anti-aliasing by the command line?

Comment: Couldn't find mention of anything explicitly for that, but maybe [export actions](https://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/index.php?title=Using_the_Command_Line#Export_files) hold the answer.

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos Thank you for the answer! But I couldn't find there the solution.

Comment: I don't think that part of the GUI is currently exposed to the command line.

Comment: I agree with @Moini. You can use ImageMagick, there is an [option](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/antialiasing/) to turn off the antialias.

Comment: ImageMagick uses Inkscape to render SVGs so I don't think it will be able to render an aliased image either.

Comment: I have found that GIMP has an artistic filter, SLIC (Simple Linear Iterative Clustering), that within GIMP does exactly what I need. In theory, it is available through the GIMP command line by invoking some bits of the "Script Fu" interface. I found a stand-alone program, gmic, that implements the GIMP filters, and I have been able to invoke the slic operation from the command line, but the results look nothing at all like the results in GIMP.

Answer (score 0):

Version 1.3 seems to have the new `--export-png-antialias` command line option, which you can set to 0 (none) to 3 (best)

Here is the source code showing the new version:

https://gitlab.com/inkscape/inkscape/-/blob/master/src/actions/actions-output.cpp?ref_type=heads#L315